# Get user logged into android device with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing an app with Flutter. Firstly for android.

This app will run only in my company phones.
And these phones have an Google account active. This account is the employee's account.

I need to get info of this account. The user's email at least.

Can I do this with Flutter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to Android’s [AccountManager.getAccounts()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager), right?

For now, there is this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/account_manager_plugin that may be somewhat sufficient for you.

```
... async {
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  try {
    List<dynamic> accounts = await AccountManagerPlugin.getAccounts;
  } on PlatformException {}
}
```

However, if you need more AccountManager features, then you’ll have to dive into its [source](https://github.com/Yeikel200/account_manager_plugin) to jumpstart and create your own plugin, wait for one to be available, or integrate your own [Android-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Please note that from Android 8.0 or higher, you cannot just directly call this anymore due to [new security restrictions around user accounts](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#aaad). (but there is a temporary trick workaround by additionally adding and requesting for the READ_CONTACTS permission)

(*and don’t forget about first enabling/requesting the permissions before running that code.*)

Comment: Hello TWL! I've been reading about AccountManager class. I think is not I want. May be I'm wrong, but I want the owner's account (in a device, go Settings > Accounts). Like in this image: https://ibb.co/zSKwPvb
Am I wrong? Is not AccountManager? Comment, too, I've tried and show me an empty list, like image shows, I have an active account in my device.

Comment: Yes, AccountManager is what you want. Did you make sure to enable all the permissions (2 permissions)? If you don't, you'll get a empty result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package

Comment: May be I've not explain me right, or may be I've not understand all that this package do.
I think this package make the user signing in with google. But I doesn't need this. I need get the user's email from the google account added into android device. I hope I've explain me correctly this time. If I wrong with package's usage, please, make me know it. Thank you!

Comment: have u got this @SeiyaJapon? Im also looking for this. Thanks

Comment: I remember that I finish this development. But it was many time ago and was the single project that I have worked with flutter. I don't remember how. I think it was using Firebase Authentication. I hope it is useful for you.